# React hooks setstate change only reflects first change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to have a food filter page whereby the user presses buttons to indicate their preference so that on confirm, I would be able to have the user's preference stored as on object with keys `"area", "cuisine" and "price"`. After trying various combinations, the logged object I get keeps only reflecting a change in the first update which is area. `{"area": "South", "cuisine": Array [], "price": -Infinity }` instead of `{"area":"South", "cuisine": "Japanese Cuisine", "price": 3}`. How do I deal with this async nature of `setstate` to get all the updates correct? (the handle press functions are passed to children component for area cuisine and price)

[image]

Filter.js

```
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState({});

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setFilters({ area: "", cuisine: "", price: 0 });
    }, []);

    const handleAreaPress = (area) => {
        setFilters((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, area: area }));
    };

    const handleCuisinePress = (cuisine) => {
        setFilters((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, cuisine: cuisine }));
    };

    const handlePricePress = (price) => {
        let max = Math.max(...price);
        setFilters((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, price: max }));
    };

    const handleConfirmPress = () => {
        console.log(filters);  // expected log to be {"area":"South", "cuisine": "Japanese Cuisine", "price": 3}
    };
```

Area.js

```
const AreaSelection = ({ handleAreaPress }) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
    const areas = ["North", "South", "East", "West", "Central"];

    const handlePress = (area) => {
        setSelected(area);
    };

    const buttons = () =>
        areas.map((items) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={items}
                onPress={() => {
                    handlePress(items);
                    handleAreaPress(items);
                }}
                style={[
                    styles.button,
                    {
                        backgroundColor: selected.includes(items)
                            ? "silver"
                            : "white",
                    },
                ]}
            >
```

Cuisine.js

```
const CuisineSelection = ({ handleCuisinePress }) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
    const cuisine = [
        "Asian",
        "Western",
        "Chinese",
        "Korean",
        "Indian",
        "Japanese",
        "Cafe",
        "Local",
    ];

    const handlePress = (cuisine) => {
        selected.includes(cuisine)
            ? setSelected(selected.filter((s) => s !== cuisine))
            : setSelected([...selected, cuisine]);
    };

    const buttons = () =>
        cuisine.map((items) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={items}
                onPress={() => {
                    handlePress(items);
                    handleCuisinePress(selected);
                }}
                style={[
                    styles.button,
                    {
                        backgroundColor: selected.includes(items)
                            ? "silver"
                            : "white",
                    },
                ]}
            >
```

Comment: Do you have a single button that is calling all 3 handler functions?

Comment: @vunski the screen is divided into 3 sections so for example area section has North South East West buttons that onPress will call handleAreaPress, same goes for the rest of the sections.

Comment: Can't really wrap my head in this as I can't try it, obviously easiest solution would be splitting all 3 into their own useState.

Comment: How are you calling those filters? I think it's better if you add the rest of the component's code.

Comment: @Clarity alright I've updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area code is actually working correct. The issue is in this code where you call two functions setting state:

```
    handlePress(items);
    handleCuisinePress(selected);
```

`handlePress` sets the internal component state, and then `handleCuisinePress` reads that state and sets it on the filters. However, since setting state is async when `handleCuisinePress` is called, it uses the old values of state since the `handlePress` results aren't applied yet.

The best way to handle this wold be to get rid of internal component state and read it directly from the filters:

```
// Declare array outside of component to not create it on every render
const cuisine = [
        "Asian",
        "Western",
        "Chinese",
        "Korean",
        "Indian",
        "Japanese",
        "Cafe",
        "Local",
    ];

const CuisineSelection = ({ handleCuisinePress, cuisine }) => {
    const buttons = () =>
        cuisine.map((items) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={items}
                onPress={() => {
                    handleCuisinePress(items);
                }}

            >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const handlePress = (cuisine) => {
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selected.includes(cuisine)) {
      newSelected = selected.filter((s) => s !== cuisine);
    } else {
      newSelected = selected.concat(cuisine);
    }

    setSelected(cuisine);
    handleCuisinePress(newSelected);
};
```

The `selected` state you pass to `handleCuisinePress` is not up to date, you shouldn't rely on it, just pass the new state you calculated in `handlePress` to `handleCuisinePress`

Answer (score 0):

You can define an expected value range and conditionally fallback to a default value.

```
    const handlePricePress = (price) => {
        const max = price >= 0 ? Math.max(...price) : 0;
        setFilters((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, price: max }));
    };
```

Comment: Sorry this does not help with the problem I'm facing due to async nature of setstate

Comment: Can you substantiate what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Once pressing the buttons for each section, on confirmation press the log I expect to get should be  {"area":"South", "cuisine": "Japanese Cuisine", "price": 3} , but I'm getting {"area": "South", "cuisine": Array [], "price": -Infinity } instead so I'm not really sure how to get the state to update correctly